# Java: How to check whether given time lies between two times?

Tags: java, time, java-8, java-time

I want to check whether target time lies between two given times without considering date using Java8 time. Let say if starting time is **"21:30"** , ending time is **"06:30"** and target time is **"03:00"**, so program should return true.

```
    @Test
    public void posteNuit()
    {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

        String s = "21:30";
        String e = "06:30";

        String t = "03:00";

        LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse(s, format);
        LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse(e, format);
        LocalTime targetTime = LocalTime.parse(t, format);

        if ( targetTime.isBefore(endTime) && targetTime.isAfter(startTime) ) {
            System.out.println("Yes! night shift.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not! night shift.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are not using date then 03:00 will always be before 21:30.

Comment: As an aside, you don’t need an explicit formatter. `LocalTime.parse("21:30")` yields the expected time. This is because your time strings conform with ISO 8601, the default format for the `java.time` classes. The format allows for optional seconds and fraction of second, though, so if you require making sure these are not present int the string, better keep your formatter.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for telling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've used LocalTime which doesn't store date information, only time.
Then you are trying to check if target time is after start time (`03:00` after `21:30`). This statement is false.

Your start time should be before end time.

If you need to handle night shift try following:

```
    if (startTime.isAfter(endTime)) {
        if (targetTime.isBefore(endTime) || targetTime.isAfter(startTime)) {
            System.out.println("Yes! night shift.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not! night shift.");
        }
    } else {
        if (targetTime.isBefore(endTime) && targetTime.isAfter(startTime)) {
            System.out.println("Yes! without night shift.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not! without night shift.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in your scenario it seems that if startTime > endTime no matter what's targetTime you'll return true.

So update the if statement:

```
if (( startTime.isAfter(endTime) && targetTime.isBefore(startTime)
        && targetTime.isAfter(endTime)  )
     || ( startTime.isBefore(endTime) && targetTime.isBefore(endTime) 
        && targetTime.isAfter(startTime) )) {
```

Comment: Your condition is always returning true regardless of targetTime let say if target time is 21:29 it should return false not true.

Comment: I don't understand. 21:29 should return false and 21:30 should return true? can you give use cases because maybe the question is unclear

Comment: understood and wrote the solution

Comment: e.g any given time which will lie in between 21:30 (09:30 PM) and 06:30 (06:30 AM) program should return true otherwise false. and Okay let me try your condition.