# How to check time lies within a range?

Tags: java, datetime

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518534/java-how-to-check-whether-given-time-lies-between-two-times) and my problem is similar but not exactly identical. I have many timestamps in problem and they are all in the form "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS", so I am parsing the string as follow:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS").parse("20180301050630663")
```

which will output `2018-03-01T05:06:30.663` (I do not know what the "T" in the middle stands for and do not know how to get rid of it)

Problem is I only care about the timestamps that lies within the range of `[09:15:00.000am -12:00:00.000pm]` and `[15:15:00.000pm -18:00:00.000pm]` across all different dates (inclusive too, meaning that if the timestamp is exactly at 09:15:00.000, then it should return true too).

However, how should I tackle this problem **because sometimes the dates could be different**, i.e. it could be across different dates `2018-03-01T05:06:30.663`, `2018-03-02T10:36:30.596`,`2018-03-11T05:06:30.663`? Since the date and times always come together, shall I extract the time from the timestamp ? What is the best way to deal with this in this situation ? I am not too familiar with the datetime libraries in Java.

Comment: `2018-03-01T05:06:30.663` is the default `toString()` which renders it in ISO-8601 time format. There is no need to "get rid of it [the T]".

Comment: why try to extract? besides: monday 9.30 might be before tuesday 9.00, but if you only check the hour, you get a different result

Comment: What is the desired result if the date is different? Do you want to include the timestamp if it’s between the times no matter the date?

Comment: Sorry. I want to include the timestamp as long as they  are within the range specified above, across different dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Rather than use [`DateTimeFormatter.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), you can pass this formatter to [`LocalTime.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) which will effectively discard the date portion of the timestamp. You can then use [`Comparable.compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) to see whether it's in the ranges you've given.

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");

LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("20180301050630663", formatter);

if  (time.compareTo(LocalTime.of(9, 15)) >= 0
  && time.compareTo(LocalTime.of(12, 0)) <= 0)
{
    System.out.println("First period");
}
else if (time.compareTo(LocalTime.of(15, 15)) >= 0
      && time.compareTo(LocalTime.of(18, 0 )) <= 0)
{
    System.out.println("Second period");
}
```

If your ranges were exclusive rather than inclusive, you could have used [`LocalTime.isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-) and [`LocalTime.isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-) which would have resulted in slightly nicer looking code.

Comment: Correct answer. My taste: (1) Parse into `LocalDateTime` as in the question, then use its `toLocalTime` method for converting. (2) Negate `isBefore` to mean “on or after”: `! time.isBefore(LocalTime.of(9, 15))`, and similar with “before or on”.

Comment: maybe better approach will be to use `isBefore()` on LocalDateTime

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx I did say that at the bottom of my answer, but thanks. Ole is probably right that using `!time.isBefore` is the most readable

Comment: Ah, yes, I did not notice, fine